# How to Extract Text From a Landscape PDF File

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to extract the text from the landscape pdf file, I'm using iTextSharp, for Portrait pages, it works well but returns an empty string for Landscape pages.

here is my code

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFile);
int intPageNum = reader.NumberOfPages;
var sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 1; i <= intPageNum; i++) {
  var text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());
  sb.Append(text + "\n");
}
```

Comment: The text extraction capabilities of itext usually don't depend on page orientation. Thus, most likely there is a different issue in your landscape file. Can you share it for analysis?

Comment: Yes, you are right iTextSharp doesn't depend on page orientation, actually, the PDF file I'm processing with iTextSharp is not TextShearchable pdf, it is a scanned one, but now the question is how do I convert a scanned PDF to TextSearchable PDF and extract text from it

Comment: You need to apply OCR. For iText 7 there is an OCR module, [pdfOCR](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/pdf-ocr-text-recognition) which integrates the well-known OCR software Tesseract.